# Unable to get WCF config to work with https

Tags: wcf, https, wcf-binding, config, channelfactory

I have looked at many different questions and responses regarding this issue but still cannot find the right solution.  I have a web service that I am connecting to via code.  The webservice is up and running on a dev machine.  I am running IIS 7.  I can connect to my service through IE at both http and https addresses.  From code I can access the http but I get an error 404 no endpoint listening when trying to access via https.  This seems like it would be simple but I am missing something obviously.

SERVER web.config looks like:
(relative portions only)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="behaviorAction" name="CI.PCI.ServiceImplementations.SPPService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HostBinding"
          contract="CI.PCI.ServiceContracts.ISPPService" listenUri="https://cisppdev.children.org/sppservices/sppservices.svc" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorAction">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SafenetTokenServiceSoap11Binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="327680" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="327680"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="HostBinding" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="true" maxBufferSize="327680" maxReceivedMessageSize="327680">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


From the client code I am dynamically creating a connection which basically goes like this:

BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
url = Settings1.Default.DevURL; -- (https://cisppdev.children.org/sppservices/sppservices.svc)
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(url);

                binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
                binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
                binding.MaxBufferSize = 327680;
                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 327680;
                binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
                binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;


                ChannelFactory<ServiceContracts.ISPPService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContracts.ISPPService>(binding, ep);

                factory.Open();

                ServiceContracts.ISPPService channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

No matter what I have tried I cannot seem to find the right configuration to make this work.  I dont have a certificate, I just want to call https service rather than http.  Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use https, you have to provide a certificate, read these links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6ffe535f-d20e-4bc0-a94a-4bc18a1206c0/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx